# Jquery Age Gate is off by one year

Tags: jquery

When 2020 came about, my age gate stopped working and seems to be off by one year. I felt like changing the 2019 to 2020 would fix it, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help here would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks!

I'm thinking this might be a simple fix but I'm a bit lost.

```
(function ($) {
  $.ageCheck = function (options) {
    var months = ['Month','January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    var month;
    const settings = $.extend({
      minAge: 21,
      redirectTo: 'index2.html',
      redirectOnFail: '',
      title: '',
      copy: '',
      successMsg: {
        header: 'Success!',
        body: 'You are now being redirected...'
      },
      underAgeMsg: 'Sorry, you are not old enough to view this site...',
      errorMsg: {
        invalidMonth: 'Please select a month.',
        invalidDay: 'Please select a day.',
        invalidYear: 'Please select a year.',
        underAge: 'You must be 21 years of age or older to view this site.'
      }
    }, options);

    const _this = {
      month: '',
      day: '',
      year: '',
      age: '',
      errors: []
    }

    function setValues() {
        const day = $('.ac-container .day').val();
        _this.month = $('.ac-container .month').val();
        _this.day = day.replace(/^0+/, ''); // remove leading zero
        _this.year = $('.ac-container .year').val();
      }

    function validate() {
        _this.errors = [];

        console.log(_this.month);

        if (_this.month == 0) {
          _this.errors.push(settings.errorMsg.invalidMonth);
        }

        if (/^([0-9]|[12]\d|3[0-1])$/.test(_this.day) === false) {
          _this.errors.push(settings.errorMsg.invalidDay);
        }

        if (/^(19|20)\d{2}$/.test(_this.year) === false) {
          _this.errors.push(settings.errorMsg.invalidYear);
        }
        clearErrors();
        displayErrors();
        return _this.errors.length < 1;
      }

    function clearErrors() {
        $('.errors').html('');
    }

    function displayErrors() {
        console.log("show errors");
        let html = '<ul>';
        for (let i = 0; i < _this.errors.length; i++) {
          html += '<li>' + _this.errors[i] + '</li>';
        }
        html += '</ul>';
        setTimeout( function() {
          $('.ac-container .errors').html(html);
        }, 200);
        setTimeout( function() {
          $(".ac-container .errors").show();
        }, 200);

      }
    function reCenter(b) {
        b.css('top', '${Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - (b.outerHeight() + 150)) / 2))}px');
        b.css('left', '${Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - b.outerWidth()) / 2))}px');
      }

      function buildHtml() {
        const copy = settings.copy;

        let html = '';
        html += '<div class="ac-overlay"></div>';
        html += '<div class="ac-container" style="padding: 1% 4% 0 1% !important;">';
        //html += `<h2>${settings.title}</h2>`;


        html += '<div class="fields" style="margin-top:15px;">';
        //html += `<p>${copy.replace('[21]', `<strong>${settings.minAge}</strong>`)}`; +'</p>';
        html += '<div><img src="images/decoration-1.png" /></div>';
        html += '<div><img src="images/enter-bday-2.png" /></div>';

        html += '<div class="errors" style="margin: 0 auto; padding: 15px 0 !important;"></div>';

        html += '<div style-"margin: 0 auto;"><select class="month">';

        for (let i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
          html += '<option value="' + i + '">' + months[i] + '</option>';
        }

        html += '</select>';
        html += '<select class="day">';
        html += '<option value="Day">Day</option>';

        for (let i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
          html += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
        }

        html += '</select>';
        html += '<select class="year">';
        html += '<option value="Year">Year</option>';
```

This is where I think the problem is (the following line:)

```
        for (let i = 2019; i > 1918; i--) {
          html += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
        }

        html += '</select></div>';
        //html += '<h2>Please select your city</h2>';
        //html += '<select class="city">';
        //html += `<option value="0">City</option>`;
        //html += `<option value="Indianapolis">Atlanta</option>`;
        //html += '</select>';

        html += '<div class="enter" style="margin-top:1%;"><button><img src="images/button-enter.png?1" /></button></div>';
        html += '<div style="padding-top:15px !important;"><img src="images/legal-4.png" /></div>';
        html += '</div></div>';

        $('body').append(html);

        $('.ac-overlay').animate({
          opacity: 0.8,
        }, 500, function () {
          reCenter($('.ac-container'));
          $('.ac-container').css({
            opacity: 1,
          });
        });

        $('.ac-container .day, .ac-container .year').focus(function () {
          $(this).removeAttr('placeholder');
        });
      }
      function setAge() {
        _this.age = '';
        const birthday = new Date(_this.year, _this.month, _this.day);
        const ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime();
        const ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
        _this.age = Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
      }
      function setSessionStorage(key, val) {
        try {
          sessionStorage.setItem(key, val);
          return true;
        } catch (e) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      function handleSuccess() {
        console.log("success");
        const successMsg = '';
        $('.ac-container').html(successMsg);
        setTimeout( function() {
          $('.ac-container').animate({
            top: '-350px',
          }, 100, function() {
            $('.ac-overlay').animate({
              opacity: '0',
            }, 100, function () {
              if (settings.redirectTo !== '') {
                window.location.replace(settings.redirectTo);
                $(".gated_content").show();
              } else {
                $('.ac-overlay, .ac-container').remove();
              }
            });
          });
        }, 100);
      }
      function handleUnderAge() {
        _this.errors.push(settings.errorMsg.underAge);
        clearErrors();
        displayErrors();
        return _this.errors.length < 1;
        // const underAgeMsg = '<h3>${settings.underAgeMsg}</h3>';
        // $('.ac-container').html(underAgeMsg);
        // if (settings.redirectOnFail !== '') {
        //   setTimeout(() => {
        //     window.location.replace(settings.redirectOnFail);
        //   }, 2000);
        // }
      }


    if (sessionStorage.getItem('ageVerified') === 'true') {
      $(".gated_content").attr("style","display:block;");
      console.log("SHOW STUFF");
      window.location.replace(settings.redirectTo);
      return false;
    }

    buildHtml();

    $('.ac-container button').on('click', function() {
      setValues();
      if (validate() === true) {
        setAge();

        if (_this.age >= settings.minAge) {
          if (!setSessionStorage('ageVerified', 'true')) {
            console.log('sessionStorage not supported by your browser');
          }
          handleSuccess();
          $(".gated_content").attr("style","");
        } else {
          handleUnderAge();
        }
      }
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
      reCenter($('.ac-container'));
      setTimeout(function() {
       reCenter($('.ac-container'));
      }, 500);
    });
  };

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your bug has to do with the fact that we are still in January. Remember that in JavaScript months are zero-based (so January is zero, not 1), which may be causing your script to think that we are still in 2019. Right now your months array has January as value 1, rather than 0 (you have "Months" as zero).

`new Date().getMonth(); // will return 0 right now, in January`

So when creating your HTML based on your months array, you'll want to either remove that first "Months" string, or use i-1 instead of i for each options value.

`html += '<option value="' + (i - 1) + '">' + months[i] + '</option>';`

One more note: you can save yourself some time in the future by replacing the `2019` in `for (let i = 2019; i > 1918; i--) {` with `new Date().getUTCFullYear()` or `new Date().getFullYear()`, so you won't have to update this line every year.

Comment: Thank you for the breakdown on why this wasn't working. I am trying to implement these changes now, but I am curious about the UTCFullYear. Will I need to adjust for my timezone in this one? And depending on the time of the year, we are either -6 or -7, so maybe that wouldn't be the best choice?

Comment: You're welcome. I agree on the time zone- personally I always just use getFullYear() instead of getUTCFullYear() (I mainly just mentioned it because I saw that you were using getUTCFullYear() in another part of your code). Non-UTC functions like getFullYear() will get the date and time based on the current device so in almost all cases, it should suit your needs just fine.